# Openmp consumes all the CPU power before even compiling/running the code? (parallel for)

Tags: c++, for-loop, openmp, cpu-usage, clion

I was looking for a way to parallelize "for loops", without implementing pthread routines, and so on, by myself. I stumbled over openmp, and the `#pragma omp parallel for default(none)` directive. Since my for loop has several variables which are "shared" (like some integer values, and also some arrays where I want to store stuff I calculate in the loop, at the respective index position),  I have added `shared(variable1, variable2, ...)` and so on. However by doing so, I noticed that the warnings in CLion which highlight the shared variables, won't go away. Furthermore I noticed that when I put the shared clause in my code, all of my 6 CPU cores start getting busy with most of the time 100 percent usage.

This seems super odd to me, since I haven't even compiled the code yet. The cores start working as soon as I put the shared() clause with some variables to the code.

I have never worked with openmp so I dont know, if I am may using it wrong? Would be great if someone can help me out with that, or probably give a hint why this happens.

**Edit:**
For clarification: With warnings, I mean, that the IDE underlines in red all the variables which seem to be shared. The CPU consumption is by the IDE itself, when adding the shared() clause to the code. However I have no clue why adding this clause would consume all the CPUs this much?

Comment: "which highlight the shared variables, won't go away" Hm, too many things here are mixed up I think. What warnings do you mean exactly? Do you have Intellisense-like plugins enabled? Did you check, which processes exactly go busy here?

Comment: sorry for not being specific enough: so i use the following directive:
#pragma omp parallel for default(none) shared(variables1, variable2, etc)  

Before I put the "shared" here, the IDE (clion) underlines in red, all the variables which seem to be "shared" , e.g. each iteration reads or writes to them (however the writes are just to arrays at the respective index). I have no explicit plugins, but the Clion out-of-the-box behaviour (regarding intellisense, Clang-tidy, etc..) 

The CPU is consumed by the IDE, but it just starts when I put the shared() clause in the code.

Comment: To display all these nice warnings and errors, Clion *has* to compile the code. Secretly and in the backgroung, but it does.

Comment: If you use `default(none)` you have to declare all variables as `shared`, `private`, `firstprivate` depending on the actual usage in the code. If you miss one variable that is used inside the `parallel` region, but you did not add a data-sharing clause for it, then it's an error and so, you're not getting warnings from your IDE, but real compiler errors.

Comment: The problem somehow went away. I think it was probably as @U.W. suggested, that the IDE was doing some kind of compilation or so in the background (idk) and that somehow consumed a lot of processing power.